# Multiple binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I need to create *multiple trees* in order to **compare** their shape and calculate how many *different shapes* of trees I got (identical forms will be counted as one form).

Input will be:

*trees* (how many trees need to be(from 1 to 50) *layers* (how many nodes will be in 1 tree (from 1 to 20)

*values* (values in every tree (from 1 to 1000000))

**Input with images:**

```
5 3
3 8 2
4 2 5
2 6 10
3 7 6
10 8 4
```

There must be *five* trees with *three* nodes in each.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The first two trees are the *same shape*, the others are different.

Output: **4**

Example of input:

```
2 2
1 2 
2 1
```

So there must be *two* trees with *two* nodes in each.

Answer is **2** because there can be 2 different forms of trees

Another example of input:

```
6 7
7 6 3 5 4 2 1 
1 3 2 4 7 5 6 
4 7 1 2 5 3 6 
5 1 6 7 2 4 3 
1 3 2 5 6 4 7 
6 7 1 5 4 2 3
```

Answer: 6

I was able to create one tree with the structure, but I can't figure out how to create several and how to compare their shapes

Maybe I don't need multiple trees.
Maybe I'll create one tree, write values to it, then somehow "save" its shape, clear it, and then write the next tree to it.

What would be the best way to do it?

**UPD:**
How can i properly deallocate allocated memory? (i know about `free()` but i dont know how to use it in this case)

Comment: I don't understand how you want to compare the "shape" : If you put "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" in this order, you end up with a tree that look like a linked list (every rigth node have a child). If you put "7 6 5 4 3 2 1" in this order, you end up with a tree that look like a linked list but mirored (every left node have a child). Are those two tree different shape ? What do you means by "shape" ?

Comment: I added a picture to make it clearer

Comment: Where does this challenge come from?

Comment: By the way, I don't really understand why you feel it's difficult to keep multiple trees. (It's not really relevant; your last paragraph is really the answer: after you build the tree, you record its shape, which only requires a `uint64_t`. After that, you don't need the tree any more; you just need to keep an array of shapes, which you can sort and uniquify at the end.) All the same, you evidently know how to use malloc to create new tree nodes, so a new tree won't interfere with any previous trees, if you wanted to keep them all around.

Comment: OK, I found it. If anyone else is interested, it's from the 2016 ICPC world finals (and is an astoundingly simple problem for that competition); if you want to give it a try, it's on [kattis](https://open.kattis.com/problems/ceiling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the compare function :

```
bool IdenticalTreeShape(struct node *tree1, struct node *tree2)
{
    if (!tree1 && !tree2) {
        return true;
    }
    if (  (!tree1)
        ||(!tree2)
        ||(!IdenticalTreeShape(tree1->left, tree2->left)
        ||(!IdenticalTreeShape(tree1->right, tree2->right) ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Now, you need to retain every uniq shape you found in order to see if a new proposition would be uniq or not.
You can do it in many way.

For example :

Have an array arrayUniq of the number of tree that you will input.
Have an integer nbUniq set to 0.

Input and create your tree in arrayUniq[nbUniq]

Compare all tree shape from "0" to "nbUniq - 1" against arrayUniq[nbUniq].
If none tree are identical, increase nbUniq.

Done :)

Comment: how can i create tree in array?

Comment: @ОляШвенда Since your number max of tree is 50, you can do `struct node *treeList[50];`. You now have an array with 50 pointer that you can use like `root` from your main function (like `insertnumber(&treeList[3], item);` if you want to use the fourth tree). Don't forget to initialize all value of treeList to NULL, and since yo do malloc, don't forget to free all allocated space !

Comment: This involves comparing every tree to every other tree, which is quadratic in the number of trees. That's not drastic for 50 trees, but it certainly can be improved considerably. (O(n log n) using sort or expected O(n) using a hash table.)

Comment: I updated the code, can you help with the free() function?

Comment: @rici well, you're rigth, but I don't expect a school homework needing nuclear science involved. Talking about hash table to someone who have trouble with binary tree, it's not going to end well. At max, sorting the array each time a solution is added + doing a dichotomic search should be feasible.

Comment: @ОляШвенда you need to take a paper, a pencil, and see exactly what you malloc and where it is. Then try to do an attempt. Hint : you free a node when his left child AND his rigth child are freed.

Comment: @Tom's: a good solution doesn't need nuclear science :-) and I suspect that an O(n²) solution wouldn't be good enough for the original source. The question I have, which I suppose I should ask on Meta: is the role of SO to provide inferior answers which might be "good enough for the OP", or is our goal to provide high-quality solutions independent of the source of the question? And in the latter case, how do we deal with programming contests, which are supposed to measure programming skills, not begging for answers skills? This is why I often don't answer questions which look like contests.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code (too long for a comment):

```
bool SameShape(node* tree1, node* tree2)
{
  if (isNull(tree1))
    if isNull(tree2))
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  else
    if (!isNull(tree2))
      return false;
  if (isNull(tree1->left) != isNull(tree2->left))
    return false;
  if (isNull(tree1->right) != isNull(tree2->right))
    return false;
  bool same = true;
  if (!isNull(tree1->left))
    same = SameShape(tree1->left, tree2->left);
  if (same && !isNull(tree1-right)
    same = SameShape(tree1-right, tree2->right);
  return same;
}
```

}